# Making Only Links in Post Underlined

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, blogger, blogs

I'm trying to make only the links contained in posts on my blog underlined using CSS. Is there a way to only have linked featured in posts underlined without making all links underlined site-wide?

My blog is hosted on Blogger and uses the Simple template - http://nickalive.blogspot.com

Thank-you for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by using the following CSS -

```
.post-body a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This will only target anchor tags present within the post content